# Параллельный запуск тестов testNG

Tags: java, maven, gradle, test-automation, testng

Использую gradle + testNG

Тесты динамически генерируют xml файлы с suite

В результате есть файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="Suite" parallel="instances">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="test-suite.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="test2-suite.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Как запустить выполнение данных suite параллельно?

В документации есть пример с maven и -suitethreadpoolsize

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites

Но это решение не подходит для gradle

Поискал в интернете и не нашел работающего решения

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска suite файла в Gradle с параллельным выполнением, вы можете использовать плагин TestNG и конфигурировать его с параметром parallel.

Ниже приведен пример build.gradle файла:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.testng' version '6.14.3'
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.1.0'
}

test {
  useTestNG() {
    suites 'path/to/your/suite.xml'
    parallel 'instances'
  }
}
```

Затем вы можете запустить тесты, выполнив команду ./gradlew test.