# testng параллелизация групп тестов

Tags: java, testng

Вопрос такого плана.
Есть TestNG, Selenide, набор тестовых классов.
На данный момент 1 класс - 1 тест. Для каждого теста, по сценарию, требуется вход на сайт с уникальной парой логин пароль. Тестов на данный момент около 20 и их количество увеличивается. Но учеток мало - 2 штуки.

Есть идея их запараллелить. Как запустить параллельные последовательности тестов исходя из 2х учеток? Есть две идеи.

Первая идея - создать 2 группы тестов (по количеству учеток), где тесты в каждой группе будут проходить последовательно друг за другом, используя одну учетку. При этом группы будут прогоняться параллельно.
В TestNG есть только методы параллелизации тестовых классов и тестовых методов. А вот как запараллелить группы или может быть даже сьюты?

Вторая идея, прогонять их параллельно по 2 штуки исходя из количества учеток, разбив на 10 групп. Как лучше реализовать этот процесс? Как прописать такое поведение в конфигурационном xml? Нигде нет ответа

Возможно есть еще другие, более надежные и проверенные способы?

Comment: Наверное расставить тэги и запускать с `parallel="tests"` типа как тут ответили: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1491555/184031